# Appending angularjs in Html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

OK this is the code. Here once the button is clicked i want to show value of list in ul .

js file

```
$('#myBox').append("<li ng-repeat='name in event'>"{{name}}"</li>");
```

html file

```
<ul id='myBox'></ul>
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="sometask()">Click me</div>
```

Once Click is clicked i want to display value of list in ul but i am unable to see the result .
if i need to append simple value then i would have done this

```
var name = "Hello World";
$('#myBox').append("<li>"+name+"</li>");
```

But using ng-repeat i couldnt use this thing. So please help me .

Thank

Comment: You need to compile your html before adding it to DOM.Using $compile service.

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/jugnu_pathak/1tdd55gj/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile your html before inserting it to DOM.

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
    myApp.controller('AngularCtrl',['$scope','$compile',function($scope,$compile){
          $scope.event = ['one','two','three','four','five'];
          $scope.sometask = function(){
              var html = $compile("<li ng-repeat='name in event'>{{name}}</li>")($scope);
             angular.element(document.querySelector('#myBox')).append(html);
          }
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your list should just live inside your controller somewhere, then your code should just append an item to the list and angular will take care of rendering it for you.

```
<div ng-controller="listCtrl">
<ul id='myBox' >
    <li ng-repeat='name in event'>
         name 
    </li>
</ul>
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="sometask()">Click me</div>
```

then in your controller you should have something like:

```
$scope.sometask = function() {
    event.push("new name") ;
}
```